# Banach spaces associated to Sobolev Towers

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

In the book *One Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations*, the authors provide some definitions as follows:

> (Page 124). [For $A \in \mathcal{L}(X)$, define] For each $n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in D(A^n)$ we define the *n-norm* $$\lVert x\rVert _n: =  \lVert A^nx  \rVert $$ and call $$X_n  : = (D(A^n), \lVert \, \cdot \, \rVert _n)$$ the *Sobolev space of order n.*

> (Page 129). Let $(A, D(A))$ be a densely-defined operator on $X$ such that $\rho(A)\neq \emptyset$. [Define] For each fixed $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $$ \lVert x \rVert_{n,\lambda} : = \lVert (\lambda - A)^n x\rVert_X , \quad x \in D(A^n). $$

> (Page 515). [Let $A: D(A) \subset X \to X$ be closed and define]  $X_1 : = (D(A), \lVert \, \cdot \, \rVert _A)$ is a Banach space for the *graph norm* $$\lVert x \rVert_A : = \lVert x \rVert  + \lVert Ax \rVert , \quad x \in D(A).$$

All of this is fine. However, in the footnote of page 515, the author write

> > The definition of $X_1$ also makes sense if $A$ has [non]empty resolvent set. Since if $\rho(A)\neq \emptyset$ the graph norm and the norms $\lVert \, \cdot \, \rVert_{1,\lambda}$ from [page 129] are all equivalent, this definition of $X_1$ will not conflict with [page 124] for $n = 1$.

This however is quite puzzling for me. My understanding is that the authors are claiming the following statement:

> > Let $A : D(A) \subset X \to X$ be closed with $\lambda \in \rho(A)$. Then $(D(A), \lVert A \cdot \rVert_X)$ is a Banach space.

This seems incorrect as it would imply, due to equivalence of norms on Banach spaces, that $\lVert x \rVert_A \leq c \lVert A x \rVert_X$ for $x \in D(A)$ and thus $\lVert x \rVert_X \leq c \lVert A x \rVert_X$ making $A$ injective for no reason.

**Edit.**
My confusion arise from a larger confusion in the text. On Page 245, the authors claim (paraphrased for brevity)

> > Let $A : D(A) \subset X \to X$ be closed such that $\sigma(A) = \sigma_c \sqcup \sigma_u$ are closed-disjoint. If $\sigma_c$ is compact then there exists a spectral decomposition $X = X_c \oplus X_u$ for $A$ such that $$ X^A_1 = X_c \oplus (X_u)^{A_u} $$ where $A_u : = A|_{X_u}$ (and $X^A_1$ is as introduced in (page 129))

I am really unsure what does $X^A_1$ mean here. Which norm are we talking about here as there isn't some a-priori fixed $\lambda \in \rho(A)$ here which would warrant the $\lVert \, \cdot \,\rVert_{1, \lambda} $-norm nor do we have $0 \in \rho(A)$ so that we can talk of $(D(A), \lVert A \cdot \rVert)$ as a Banach space?

Comment: You are correct. But I feel like that footnote was just meant to say that if $0 \in \rho(A)$ then the two $X_1$s don't conflict with each other.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you very much for your response. Can you please also check the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original question: you are indeed, however it is entirely possible the author just meant to talk about the $X_1$ of page $124$ in the context where $0 \in \rho(A)$, since that's when $\|\cdot\|_{1,0}$ would be involved and equal to $\|\cdot\|_1$.

For the question from the edit: this equality seems to be algebraic, but even if it is topological (in the sense of [topological complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace)), all the norms introduced are equivalent so you can pick any of them. The underlying topology is the exact same and nothing here involves a property like isometric isomorphism or whatever else which isn't preserved by equivalence of norms, so there's no worry to be had.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we can pick $\lVert Ax\rVert$ norm as well? If so, wouldn't we run into the same issue as before. If you're suggesting to use $\lVert x\rVert_{1,\lambda}$ then shouldn't we specify the choice of $\lambda$ (unless this is what you mean by norms are equivalent).

Comment: @newbie To be clear, they named it $n$-norm but for $n = 1$ at least it's a norm iff $A$ is injective, let alone a complete one. I think you can basically just forget about that one unless $0$ is in the resolvent and you're looking at $\|\cdot\|_{1,0}$. (Also to be clear I would have upvoted your question but I'm out of votes for today :-) )